# Why do all SharePoint drives show same storage quota used?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am using the Microsoft Graph API and making a GET call to [/sites/{siteId}/drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-a-sites-drives)

When I do that I get a list of drives for my SharePoint site. Each drive has a "[quota](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/quota?view=graph-rest-1.0)" property and in that a "used" property.

I'm assuming this is supposed to be the amount of storage consumed by the drive, but how come all the drives show the same bytes used?

Is that because "quota" represents the quota for the entire site, and all drives are referencing the exact same quota and the same pool of used space in that quota?

For example: On one of my sites I have 3 drives, a document library named "Test", a document library named "Documents", and a document library named "Teams Wiki Data". All of them show the same quota total and the same quota used.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint in Microsoft 365 typically consists of different types of storage locations, including OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Team Sites. Each of these locations may have its own storage quota, and the usage is tracked separately.

You need ensure that you have the necessary permissions to view the storage quota for each location. If your permissions are limited, you might see the same information for all drives.

Comment: I don't think this is a permissions issue. I am a global admin in M365 and on this SharePoint site I am testing with I am a site admin and site owner. It's one SharePoint Team site with multiple drives within it. I edited my question to add an example. This seems to be the result I get for any site I query with this API.